# Why wouldn't this work for amount of 2 pairs you can make?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

$$\binom{52}{1}\binom{3}{1} + \binom{50}{1}\binom{3}{1} + \binom{48}{1}$$

My logic here is that you have $52$ cards, and you choose $1$ of those to be the number for your first pair. Then you multiply that with the amount of that number left. Then you choose the number for your second hand and then do the same thing here. The last thing $49$ choose $1$ is because I need to fill out $5$ cards for a hand (for my class), so I did $48$ choose $1$, since $52-4 = 48$.
What's wrong with this?

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  As it stands, it is not clear what you are trying to compute, nor how you are computing it. Why are you adding things, for example?

Comment: @lulu I'm trying to compute amount of 2 pairs, I just thought this logic would work since  you're picking numbers here, but the solution is different than what I have.

Comment: The number of different "2 pair" poker hands in a regular deck of cards, right?

Comment: Why are you adding? Remember the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Comment: You mean a $5$ card hand?  Details matter...don't assume your readers are thinking about the same problem you are.  In any case, I don't understand why you are adding things.

Comment: @Karl I thought you're supposed to add them since the act of choosing 2 means you're taking them out of the deck, which means that the second event of choosing 2 is dependent on the first one. Yes, this is a regular card of decks.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that switching the two pairs does not change the hand.

Comment: @lulu i'm confused when to use addition or multiplication rule, I put my logic for addition rule in comment to Karl's post. Also I did say I need to fill out 5 cards for my hand.

Comment: You only add when you are combining disjoint cases.  If you are compounding choices, you multiply.

Comment: @lulu okay I see

Comment: Also, if you choose from among $50$ cards, you risk taking an additional card from the same rank as the two cards you already selected.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Study the standard calculation you have in hand.  Make sure you understand how that one works.

Comment: @lulu i'm trying too, but I honestly don't get it.
The one I have is 13 choose 2 * 4 choose 2 * 4 choose 2 * 11 choose 1 * 4 choose 1.
Why is it 11 choose 1

Comment: Because there are only $11$ ranks to choose from.  You can't choose either of the two ranks that appear in pairs, after all.  Remember, in standard poker, two-pairs excludes a full house.

Comment: Also, you're counting e.g. K,Q and Q,K as two separate possibilities for the first two cards, even though the order of cards in the hand shouldn't matter. Try to think of a sequence of choices that ensures each possible hand is obtained in only one way. This is where binomial coefficients $\binom nk$ with $k>1$ are helpful.

Comment: Other responses have beaten your analysis to death.  Consider: first, you choose $2$ ranks out of $13$.  These will be the ranks of the pairs.  Factor is $$ \binom{13}{2}.$$  For each such rank, you can choose $2$ of the $4$ cards in that rank in $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2}$ ways.  So, you have the additional factor of $$\left[\binom{4}{2}\right]^2.$$  Then, you have $44$ cards remaining from the $11$ unchosen ranks.  Factor is $$44.$$  Putting it all together, the enumeration is $$\binom{13}{2} \times \left[\binom{4}{2}\right]^2 \times 44.$$